# Dynamically permissions based on routes path in laravel via entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

To create a Role/permission bases laravel app I'm using [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) package.

Now I want to use an approach that no need to assign defined perms to routes as different middlewares in `web.php` and that is:

First fetches all defined routes (via `Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes()` ) and store each of them in `permissions` table.

We can get all routes by this code:

```
$routes = collect(Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes())->reduce(function ($carry = [], $route) {

            $carry[] = $route->uri();
            return $carry;
        });
```

On the other hand we can define roles that have those permissions and attach those to user in normal way.

Now when a user want to access a page , first we get route path name and then by `can` method defined in entrust we check that user can access to that route or not. this can done via a simple middleware named `checkAccess` for example that is added to all routes as a route group. like this:

```
class checkAccess
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {

           $currentName    =   Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
            if (Auth::user()->can($currentName)) {
                return $next($request);
            }else{
                return response()->view('errors.403', ['prevPage'=> URL::previous()]);
            }*/

            return $next($request);
        }
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login');
    }
}

Route::middleware(['checkAccess'])->group(function () {
     //Other routes 
});
```

But a problem is that some resource routes have same route path but different method access. like:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------+----------------+
|  METHOD   |       URL       | Action  |   Route Name   |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+----------------+
| GET       | /photos/{photo} | show    | photos.show    |
| PUT/PATCH | /photos/{photo} | update  | photos.update  |
| DELETE    | /photos/{photo} | destroy | photos.destroy |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+----------------+
```

And this is cause duplicate permission name Although they are really different in action.

I want to know are there any relative way to create dynamically permission. or what can I do that to solve this problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is the thing that you need, but maybe it will help you. I have modular application structure and for each module one route.php file. In that file my routes depend on permission:

```
Route::get('/edit/{param?}', [
            'as' => 'get.users.edit',
            'uses' => 'UsersController@getEdit',
            'middleware' => ['permission:admin']
        ]);
```